# backbone and bootstrap js popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have a strange problem concerning bootstrap's popover and backbone.

my backbone code:

```
App.Views.UploadBox = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#upload-box',

events: {
    'click #upload-file': 'openPicker',
    'change #upload-file-input': 'handleFileUpload'
    //'mouseover #upload-file': 'hoverMessage'

},

initialize: function () {
    this.uploader = this.$('#upload-file-input');
    this.$("#upload-file").popover({ title: 'some title', content: 'helo world' });
    this.button = this.$('#upload-file');
}, ...
```

upload box:

```
<div class="span2 offset1" id="cannon-upload-box">
  <a href="#" class="btn media-header span10" 
  id="upload-file" rel="popover">UploadFile</a>
  <input id="upload-file-input" 
  type="file" placeholder="Choose File" style="display: none">
</div>
```

What the code supposed to do: when hovering over the a element (id=upload-file), the should be a popover message.

What the code is actually doing: when hovering nothing happens but when clicking the button the backbone action is triggered as desired but also the popover jump but as a constant element![image: scrrenshot taken]

Thank you for your help (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need trigger option when set up the popover, like this:

```
this.$("#upload-file").popover({ 
    title: 'some title',
    content: 'helo world' ,
    trigger: 'hover' // show up on hover default is 'click'
});
```

try it!